"Краткая аннотация" — плеоназм?
Аннотация, по сути, — кратенький рассказ про текст. В работах используется выражение "краткая аннотация", и не является ли это плеоназмом?

https://xn----ftbeziiblod5b.xn--p1ai/aktsii/kak-napisat-annotatsiyu-k-nauchnoy-rabote/#2

Это не плеоназм.

Нет, аннотация — это не плеоназм, если судить по толковому словарю Кузнецова. Аннотация бывает краткой и развернутой.
Большой толковый словарь русского языка
АННОТАЦИЯ, -и; ж. [от лат. annotatio — замечание]. Краткая характеристика тематического содержания, цели, предполагаемого адресата и других особенностей какого-л. издания или рукописи. Дать, составить, написать аннотацию к чему-л., на что-л. Снабдить аннотацией что-л. Краткая, развёрнутая а. А. статьи, очерка. А. на методическое пособие.

Да, плеоназм. Чаще всего в определении слова "аннотация." есть слово "краткий". И не встречалось информации о "длинных аннотациях". Вероятно, выражение "краткая аннотация" появилось в издательских требованиях к начинающим авторам, дабы избежать многостраничных презентаций их рукописей. Обычно просят синопис размером со страницу и "краткую аннотацию".
Что характерно, даже этого не хватает. Например, некоторые издательства вообще отчаялись до "краткая аннотация (несколько предложений)". Например, здесь.
И можно заметить, что краткие аннотации сейчас требуют на ресурсах с научными работами. Но там это профессиональное: чем больше дополнительных слов, тем более серьёзным мнит себя автор. Одинокое существительное без прилагательных — это упущенный шанс выпендриться.
Кстати, порывшись ещё, нахожу классификацию для научных работ. Там аннотации краткие, обзорные и развёрнутые. Видимо, развёрнутые как раз и выступают противоположными кратким.

Развернутыми – кроме короткого пересказа содержания и его оценки они
включают в себя еще и перечисление глав, параграфов и/или рубрик.
Обычно такая аннотация составляется к научным работам, учебникам,
монографиям и занимает от одной до нескольких страниц.

А краткие:

направлены на характеристику одного аспекта. Как правило, это оценка
материала, глубины проработки темы. Либо представляют собой очень
краткое резюме, раскрывающее самую суть произведения.

Но это, честно сказать, не меняет моего мнения высказанного в начале ответа. Аннотация остаётся сама по себе кратким описанием чего-либо. А вот эти все градации — это нишевый, специфичный вариант, для своих. Скажем, если кто-то начнёт делить книги на додесятикилограммовые и сверхдесятикилограммовые, это вовсе не значит, что мы теперь должны всюду употреблять эти уточнения. В большинстве случаев эта информация не нужна: книги плюс-минус у нас в диапазоне до десяти кг, так что чужие заморочки внедрять ни к чему.
